# x and y in parametric form

Tags: geometry

For example,
If $$x^2 + y^2 = R^2$$

$$x(t) = R\cos t $$ and $$ y(t) = R\sin t$$

But if any arbitrary relation of $x$ and $y$ is given then how to find $x(t)$ and $y(t)$?

Comment: I have an idea, so like let $F(x,y)=b$, solve $y$ for $x$. i.e $y=f(x)$. then $(t,f(t))$ would be a parametrization?

Comment: Sometime it is very hard. Which class of cases you are asking?

Comment: In general: you won't.

Comment: @mathpadawan It might not be possible to solve for either variable in terms of the other: this doesn’t even work for the given circle since  is not a function of  there. You can use the inverse function theorem to find a _local_ parameterization in that way, but in general it won’t extend to the entire curve.